# Memory leak in gRPC async_client

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, grpc, grpc-c++

I am using `gRPC` `async client` in similar way to the [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_client2.cc).

In this example (published in the `gRPC` official `github`) the client allocate memory for the message to send, using the address as `tag` for the `completion queue`, and when the message is being answered in listener thread the memory (known by the `tag`- address) is free.

I'm afraid of situation where the server is not responding to a message and the memory is never being free.

- Does the `gRPC` protect me from this situation?
- Should I implement it in a different way? (using smart pointers/save the pointers in data structure/etc...)

**Async client send function**

```
void SayHello(const std::string& user) {
    // Data we are sending to the server.
    HelloRequest request;
    request.set_name(user);

    // Call object to store rpc data
    AsyncClientCall* call = new AsyncClientCall;

    // Because we are using the asynchronous API, we need to hold on to
    // the "call" instance in order to get updates on the ongoing RPC.
    call->response_reader =
        stub_->PrepareAsyncSayHello(&call->context, request, &cq_);

    // StartCall initiates the RPC call
    call->response_reader->StartCall();

    call->response_reader->Finish(&call->reply, &call->status, (void*)call);

}
```

**Async client receive function for thread**

```
void AsyncCompleteRpc() {
    void* got_tag;
    bool ok = false;

    // Block until the next result is available in the completion queue "cq".
    while (cq_.Next(&got_tag, &ok)) {
        // The tag in this example is the memory location of the call object
        AsyncClientCall* call = static_cast<AsyncClientCall*>(got_tag);

        // Verify that the request was completed successfully. Note that "ok"
        // corresponds solely to the request for updates introduced by Finish().
        GPR_ASSERT(ok);

        if (call->status.ok())
            std::cout << "Greeter received: " << call->reply.message() << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "RPC failed" << std::endl;

        // Once we're complete, deallocate the call object.
        delete call;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    GreeterClient greeter(grpc::CreateChannel(
            "localhost:50051", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()));

    // Spawn reader thread that loops indefinitely
    std::thread thread_ = std::thread(&GreeterClient::AsyncCompleteRpc, &greeter);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        std::string user("world " + std::to_string(i));
        greeter.SayHello(user);  // The actual RPC call!
    }

    std::cout << "Press control-c to quit" << std::endl << std::endl;
    thread_.join();  //blocks forever

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the gRPC protect me from this situation?

Kinda. gRPC guarantees that all queued operations will end up in their matching completion queue sooner or later. So your code is ok as long as:

- No exception is thrown at an unfortunate time.
- You don't make a change to the code that creates a code path that doesn't include queuing the operation or deleting the call.

In other words: It's ok, but fragile.

#### Option A:

If you want to be truly robust, the way to go is `std::shared_ptr<>`. However, they can mess with multithreaded performance in unexpected ways. So  wether it's worth it or not depends on where your app lands on the performance vs robustness spectrum.

Such a refactor would look like:

1. Have `AsyncClientCall` inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this`
2. Change the construction of `call` to `std::make_shared<AsyncClientCall>()`
3. In the completion queue handler, increase the ref-count:

```
while (cq_.Next(&got_tag, &ok)) {
    auto call = static_cast<AsyncClientCall*>(got_tag)->shared_from_this();
```

And get rid of the `delete`, obviously.

#### Option B:

You can also get a decent halfway measure with `unique_ptr<>`:

```
    auto call = std::make_unique<AsyncClientCall>();
    ...
    call->response_reader->Finish(&call->reply, &call->status, (void*)call.release());
```

and

```
    std::unique_ptr<AsyncClientCall> call{static_cast<AsyncClientCall*>(got_tag)};
```

This guards against refactors and exceptions while maintaining everything else. However, this is only usable for unary rpcs that produce a single completion event. Streaming rpcs, or rpcs that exchange metadata will need completely different handling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what happen in situation where the server isn't responding to some messages? would the messages just stay and wait in the queue? can the queue overflow? can we clean the queue from old messages in this situation?

Comment: @lior.i If the server doesn't respond, the RPC will fail sooner or later, either by timeout or the socket closing, or cancelled somehow. At that point, the tag will be placed in the queue with a non-ok status.

Comment: "can we clean the queue from old messages in this situation?" You can always cancel a call. But generally, adding a deadline is plenty enough.

Comment: what do you mean by cancel the call?

Comment: [`TryCancel()`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_client_context.html#abd0f6715c30287b75288015eee628984), but as I said [`set_deadline()`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_client_context.html#ad4e16866fee3f6ee5a10efb5be6f4da6) is generally preferred because it's fire-and-forget

Comment: Also, just to make sure you are not confused. The only public-facing notion of "queue" in grpc are completion queues, which does not contain all in-flight rpcs, only the ones that have finished user-requested operations.

Comment: Great, Thanks @Frank, could you please add this information to the answer?

Comment: For Option A, the arguments to function Finish() should include a get() on smart pointer:

```call->response_reader->Finish(&call->reply, &call->status, (void*)call.get());```

Comment: `call->response_reader->Finish(&call->reply, &call->status, (void*)call.release());`

Are you sure that the call to `call.release()` will be processed _after_ the `&call->reply` and `&call->status`. If the args are processed from right-to-left, this could probably produce Access violation error.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559231/why-is-my-program-evaluating-arguments-right-to-left#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=The%20order%20of%20the%20evaluation,or%20from%20left%20to%20right.)